# Issue setting up Apache directory outside of DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to get Apache 2.4.46 configured to serve a directory outside of the DocumentRoot.

Here's my apache config:

```
  <Directory /hab/svc/dispatcher/data/static>
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Alias /static/ "/hab/svc/dispatcher/data/static/"


<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName server.domain.com
   DocumentRoot /hab/svc/dispatcher/data/www-aem

  <Directory /hab/svc/dispatcher/data/www-aem>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    Require all granted
    <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
      ModMimeUsePathInfo On
      SetHandler dispatcher-handler
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>

  <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
    DispatcherConfig /hab/svc/dispatcher/config/dispatcher.any
    DispatcherLogLevel info
    DispatcherLog /hab/svc/dispatcher/var/dispatcher.log
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
### Some other rewrite stuff too
```

Despite having the directory and the alias set up, I get on 404 requesting /static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html despite that file being there.

```
==> /hab/svc/dispatcher/var/logs/error.log <==
[Fri May 21 18:29:44 2021] [trace2] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 10.100.109.27:50333] 10.100.109.27 - - [t1xaemdapp01.domain.com/sid#1fcaef8][rid#7fd5a8002bd0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html - HOST: t1xaemdapp01.domain.com
[Fri May 21 18:29:44 2021] [trace2] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 10.100.109.27:50333] 10.100.109.27 - - [t1xaemdapp01.domain.com/sid#1fcaef8][rid#7fd5a8002bd0/initial] rewrite '/static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html' -> '/static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html?' - HOST: t1xaemdapp01.domain.com
[Fri May 21 18:29:44 2021] [trace2] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 10.100.109.27:50333] 10.100.109.27 - - [t1xaemdapp01.domain.com/sid#1fcaef8][rid#7fd5a8002bd0/initial] local path result: /static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html - HOST: t1xaemdapp01.domain.com
[Fri May 21 18:29:44 2021] [trace2] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 10.100.109.27:50333] 10.100.109.27 - - [t1xaemdapp01.domain.com/sid#1fcaef8][rid#7fd5a8002bd0/initial] prefixed with document_root to /hab/svc/dispatcher/data/www-aem/static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html - HOST: t1xaemdapp01.domain.com
[Fri May 21 18:29:44 2021] [trace1] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 10.100.109.27:50333] 10.100.109.27 - - [t1xaemdapp01.domain.com/sid#1fcaef8][rid#7fd5a8002bd0/initial] go-ahead with /hab/svc/dispatcher/data/www-aem/static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html [OK] - HOST: t1xaemdapp01.domain.com
[Fri May 21 18:29:44 2021] [debug] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 10.100.109.27:50333] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted - HOST: t1xaemdapp01.domain.com
[Fri May 21 18:29:44 2021] [debug] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 10.100.109.27:50333] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted - HOST: t1xaemdapp01.domain.com

==> /hab/svc/dispatcher/var/logs/dispatcher.log <==
[Fri May 21 18:29:44 2021] [I] [pid 60487:tid 140554406979328] "GET /static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html" - blocked [domain_ca/-] 0ms
```

As you can see from the log, Apache is looking for /static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html at /hab/svc/dispatcher/data/www-aem/static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html which is a directory that has been configured. It is then delegating to the dispatcher modules disp_apache2.c which can't retrieve it, so it returns a 404. I'm not sure why it isn't looking at /hab/svc/dispatcher/data/static/chef-claes-c4b-3/index.html even though there's an alias set up.

Any help?

Comment: Use rewrite rules carefully since they are processed very early. Earlier than alias IIRC.

Comment: Hmmm, I had almost the exact same config set up in an older Apache 2.2 instance. I did run afoul of one Rewrite rule so I modified it not to match that directory alias. So I don't think any of the rewrite rules are causing a problem.